# How to compile ArangoDB 2.8 source in CentOS?

Tags: centos, arangodb

In CentOS I cannot follow the steps given on the ArangoDB official site (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/operations/installation/compiling/) to compile ArangoDB source code.

Setup cannot be found in the setup steps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned `setup` step tells you to do:

```
make setup
```

this requires that your system has latest autoconf / automake available - which you probably don't have in CentOS. Older Autoconf / Automake will fail to generate the configure script. The configure switch `--enable-maintainer-mode` requires that the system is able to run `make setup`.

You can now continue in two ways:

- compile and install latest autofoo and restart with `make setup`
- don't use `make setup`; Flush the changes to your git working copy with `git reset --hard`.  Use `export CFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb'` and `export CXXFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb'` to make configure generate debug enabled binaries.

In general you should add more details to your Stackoverflow questions in terms of what you did, what happened - so people can better help you.

Comment: I don't understand your this sentence:" Flush the changes to your git working copy with git reset --hard. ".Can you speak clearly?thank you very much

Comment: I want to compile in centos arangodb source code, but according to the steps to do for the website is not successful, can you help me with this problem?Thank you very much!

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181816/unable-to-compile-in-centos-arangodb2-8-source you got it working meanwhile? The git reset command will undo all changes to your git clone (i.e. those done by `make setup`)

Comment: You can install the required gcc using: `yum install centos-release-scl-rh devtoolset-3-gcc devtoolset-3-gcc-c++`

Comment: after excute 'make setup',The error is "make:aclocal:Command not found;   make:*** [setup] Error 127

Comment: as noted above, install a recent autoconf, or don't run make setup.

Comment: Now after the make an error：“collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'”                         the ‘ld’ here is what mean?

Comment: ld is the linker. it should be in `/usr/bin/ld`. You may have installed `GOLD` and maybe need to symlink / copy it there.

Comment: The usr/bin directory exists a ld.  GOLD?You mean you want to install the go?Then the ld copied to usr/bin/directory?    THANKS.

Comment: I have installed the ‘ binutils - gold ’ , and the original of ‘ ld ’ changed           ‘ ld_old ’, the newly installed ‘ /usr/local/bin ’ directory of the ‘ ld ’ : ‘ sudo ln -s/usr/local/bin/ld/usr/bin/ld ’  ;But still not successful, at the same mistake

Comment: Hm, maybe this comes from the v8 build - can you re-checkout and start from beginning once more?

Comment: It is in the Building V8 when this error；                                                                                Alas, this problem is very strange, still won't do.Changed arangodb2.7 version also still won't do.I felt like I was tormented by the question is crazy.

Comment: I did not install clang and clang++; installed gcc4.9.2, do not know whether this is the cause of the error

Comment: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1339                                        I saw your comments here, I replied to you, you help me to refer to it. Thank you very much

Comment: ArangoDB 3 uses cmake, which streamlines the whole build process a lot. maybe you rather try that?